# How to modify the contents of a word document by changing Office Open XML representation of the file?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I am building an add-in for Office Word 2016 using the Word JavaScript API. As it does not provide the level of control over the document that I require I am trying to accomplish this by directly changing the OOXML of the document. Since the user can have a document with any number of pages, I am not sure if this is the right way to do this. I want to know if there is any way to simplify this like extracting only parts of the document and inserting it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question, for starters I am curious to know the level of control you are expecting in the API, I wonder if you can share more details on potential gaps (thanks in advance!).

Now, to answer to your question: absolutely! we open the door via OOXML to interact with the document. This is a very powerful tool, albeit potentially complicated (but seems to be you are knowledgeable of WordML) and it can be slow, specially in platforms other than Win32 or Mac (Word Online XML injection is sloooooooow).

The key to accomplish what you need is that you get a range (i would need a criteria more detailed on the "extracting parts of the document" you mentioned, but at the end of the day its about getting a range). Once you have it, you can actually do a range.insertOoxml("your OOXML","replace") to replace that range with whatever OOXML you have.

You can get a range by many different ways in the API. For instance the search method returns a collection of ranges. all objects have a .getRange() method you can use for this.

The following example replaces the first word of the first paragraph in the document with a given OOXML.

```js
  Word.run(function (ctx) {

             var myTempOOXML = "get some valid  OOXML!"
             ctx.document.body.paragraphs.getFirst().split([" "],false,false,false).getFirst().insertOoxml(myTempOOXML, "replace");
             return ctx.sync();


         }).catch(function (e) { app.showNotification(e.message)})
```

Hope this sets you up in the right direction.
Btw, [here is a useful article about ooxml and word.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still having a hard time in figuring out what a valid OOXML string looks like. Every time I get a range and print out its OOXML, I am getting the OOXML for the entire document and not just the OOXML for the range I am expecting.
`var paragraph = context.document.body.paragraphs.getFirst();
        paragraph.load();
        var paragraphooxml = paragraph.getOoxml();
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log(paragraphooxml.value);
        });`
This prints out OOXML for the whole document and not just for the first paragraph.

Comment: yes please read the article i fwd, it talks about how to generate as less verbose as possible XML https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md

Comment: if you write the XML you just read back to the document you will see its just the paragraph.

Comment: @JuanBalmori, dead link.  :(

Comment: @newname, I think this is the new link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/main/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md